# Need a generic uninstaller

Tags: windows, uninstall, installshield

I have a Windows program originally installed with InstallShield.  However, they seem to have neglected to add an uninstaller, so all I have is a setup log (ini format).  Is there a generic InstallShield uninstaller that can parse and execute this setup log and uninstall the program?

Edit: Something like UNWISE.EXE (which just looks for INSTALL.LOG) except for InstallShield is what I need.
Edit2: Actually, the inf seems to be a standard Windows DDK inf, but I still don't know how to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

The one that everyone seems to be using at the moment is [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). I have tried and it works very well.

If you want it quick and easily, it is available through [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com).

[Here is a direct link](http://ninite.com/installer/9d36feb306d97d679f1856c3811bcb2402ae74ee) for a Ninite installer with just Revo Uninstaller selected.

Comment: Revo was my first instinct, but the problem is that Revo depends on the original application having an uninstaller.

Comment: @mazin, not with the professional version. You can grab a 30 day fully-featured trial of Revo uninstaller pro, which includes a "forced uninstall" option. It basically searches everywhere for traces of the app and removes it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that [Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/) works pretty well.

As a bonus, it includes functionality to monitor an installation so that you can be sure to remove all the junk.

In a similar vein, [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) is very nice for isolating the installation of an application from the rest of your system. Although initially designed as a way of protecting a system from malware introduced through IE, I find it even more useful for trying out applications without having the trials leave bits of crap lying about.

Answer (score 0):

[Your Uninstaller](http://www.ursoftware.com/) is really good. It will uninstall the program as normal, then scan your computer for any files left behind by the program and deletes them. Should clear things up for you nicely.